# Does one city have to pay for the entire Great Work?

Tags: simcity-2013

When you start a Great Work, can every city contribute to the cost, or is it limited to only one city's contributions?

**EDIT:**

I'm looking to see if the initial cost in simoleon can be shared between the cities, or if one city has to pay for it all.

Comment: Well they can definitely send some money to the founding town as a gift. I didn't see any sharing options in the region view (but I haven't really created any great works myself yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can begin building a great work, the project for each great work will need to be researched in a city that has a university. This research fee can only be paid by the mayor that has the university in their city. It would be possible for the other cities to gift the money to the city that pays the bill though.

Once construction has started on the great work, each city has their own controls for contributing to the creation of your region's great work. To enable your city to send resources to the great work, you will see on this screen that underneath each resource is a 'power button' (it looks the same as the power buttons to disable buildings). Turn this *on* and you will start sending resources to your great work site.

[image]

To send resources to your great work, zoom out to the region view and click on the great work site - this will show you a status screen detailing each of the resources required to build the great work and the quantity of each resource that has already been supplied.

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually more looking for the cost to start the big projects in simoleon. I was wondering if one player has to pay it, or if multiple players can contribute to this.

Comment: Updated my answer - I am not sure if there is a fee to start building after you've done the researching, I will confirm this again tonight and update my answer for you. If there is, this will follow the same rule as the research, in that only one city will be able to pay for it but it would still be possible to gift the money from each city

Comment: There is only the initial payment to make (at least in the case of the solar farm) - after making the initial payment on the Great Works screen in region, it enters a state of "pending Great Work", where a permit to build has been submitted. I'm not sure how long this lasts for...

Answer (score 3):

Initial cost of the Great Work must be paid by the city that submits the order. Other cities can gift money to the founding city.

Resources can be contributed by any city as per kalina's post.

Answer (score 2):

The fee is paid by one city. The price depends on the great work but most of them are one million simoleons. Someone did answer you too, only one person can pay to start of, but of other cities donate to the purchaser, the impact can be lightened

Comment: The pending can take up to ten minutes, or longer depending on internet speed. My region has two great works in the process.